# Add new different sublist in a list using HashSet

Tags: c#, list, hashset, sublist

I want to add a new sublist `subroute` in list `Zlist` only if the sublist is different from other sublist in list `Zlist`. Here is the definition of `Zlist` and initial `sublists`:

```
HashSet<Matrix> Zlist = new HashSet<Matrix>();
for (int m = 0; m < M; m++)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < C + 1; i++)
    {
        Zlist.Add(new Matrix() {Column = {m,i}});
    }
}
```

here is the definition of `<Matrix>`:

```
class Matrix
{
    public List<int> Column { get; set; }

    public Matrix()
    {
        Column = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

And this is how I add my `subroute` to `Zlist`:

```
foreach (var subroute in route)
    Zlist.Add(new Matrix() { Column = subroute});
```

In my case, another list named `route` contains 2 `subroute`. Which only one is new. But based on my code, `Zlist` still add all `subroute`. I already put HashSet but it's not worked. Please help, thanks

Comment: Please don't repeat tags in question titles.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the HashMap how to do the comparison, since these are reference type.

```
public class MatrixComparer : IEqualityComparer<Matrix>
{
    public bool Equals(Matrix x, Matrix y)
    {
        if (x.Column.Count != y.Column.Count) return false;
        return !x.Column.Where((t, i) => t != y.Column[i]).Any();
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Matrix obj)
    {
        return obj.Column.Aggregate((i1, i2) => i1 ^ i2);
    }
}
```

And send it in the HashMap:

```
HashSet<Matrix> Zlist = new HashSet<Matrix>(new MatrixComparer() );
```